# How do i get the content in datasource, within the template in my custom extension for sw-data-grid component?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-data-grid

```
<sw-data-grid :dataSource="records">
<template v-slot:actions>
<sw-button v-on:click="open_popup_box( id_of_the_item )">Edit</sw-button>
</template>
</sw-data-grid>
```

How do i get the id_of_the_item within the record for that particular row here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<sw-data-grid :dataSource="records">
    <template #actions="{ item }">
        <sw-button v-on:click="open_popup_box(item.id)">Edit</sw-button>
    </template>
</sw-data-grid>
```

Comment: Tested. working fine. Can you please let me know how did you figure it out ?, Thanks